# Is a cluster needed to pin files in a ipfs private network?

Tags: ipfs

I created a ipfs private network based on a shared swarm key and I removed all the default swarm peers and added only selected peers. I added files using ipfs add and it seems to pin the file to all the peers.

Is a cluster needed to ensure files are pinned on the entire ipfs network?

Answer (score 1):

No, but it make things easier in the future.

Adding a file is just advertizing that it is available to other peers to grab.

For it to be stored by all the nodes in your private network you have 3 solutions:

1) Make all the other peers request the file. They will then keep it in their cache and it will stay there until they perform a Garbage Collection.

2) Make all your peer pin the content. It will be immune to garbage collection and be available until you unpin them.

3) Set up a cluster with ipfs-cluster to automate replication every time you pin something on one node.

Comment: Can only the master node have the files and not all other nodes in the cluster?

Comment: You mean the other nodes are clients simply requesting files on demand to the master? Then no cluster, and delegated routing + peering agreements should do the trick. But your questions would be better answered on discuss.ipfs.io